# Container with most water

Tags: javascript

I was going through following question on geeksforgeeks

> Given n non-negative integers a_1, a_2, ..., a_n  where each
>   represents a point at coordinate  (i, a_i) . ‘ n ‘ vertical lines are
>   drawn such that the two endpoints of line i is at  (i, a_i)  and (i,
>   0). Find two lines, which together with x-axis forms a container, such
>   that the container contains the most water.
>
> The program should return an integer which corresponds to the maximum
>   area of water that can be contained ( maximum area instead of maximum
>   volume sounds weird but this is 2D plane we are working with for
>   simplicity ).

Question Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/container-with-most-water/

Here, They have given following examples with explanation

```
Input : [1, 5, 4, 3]
Output : 6
Explanation : 
5 and 3 are distance 2 apart. 
So the size of the base = 2. 
Height of container = min(5, 3) = 3. 
So total area = 3 * 2 = 6

Input : [3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
Output : 12
Explanation : 
5 and 3 are distance 4 apart. 
So the size of the base = 4. 
Height of container = min(5, 3) = 3. 
So total area = 4 * 3 = 12
```

But I am still unable to figure out what does question requires me to do? like Why in the first example they have selected 2nd and last element (5 and 3) and in the second example they have selected 1st and last element?

Comment: Did you draw out the examples on some paper, based on the description? If not, do so: it explains it quite well.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am unable to comprehend how they are comparing distance apart, like selecting 5 and 3.

Comment: No, really, draw the example. Draw a horizontal line on a grid, three steps long. The vertical lines: 1 step high at the start of your horizontal. Then one 5 steps high on step to the right of that. Then on 4 steps high one step to the right of that, and finally one 3 steps high at the end of our horizontal line. There are six possible "containers" you can form with that, each will have a very obvious width, and be able to hold a very obvious number of 1 step x 1 step rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must identify which two lines from the input, when together, create the container with the most water.

For the first example, with `1, 5, 4, 3`, some of your other options are:

- 1 and 5: Result is an area of 1 (1 apart * 1 min height)
- 1 and 4: Result is an area of 2 (2 apart * 1 min height)
- 1 and 3: Result is an area of 3 (3 apart * 1 min height)
- 5 and 4: Result is an area of 4 (1 apart * 4 min height)
- 4 and 3: Result is an area of 3 (1 apart * 1 min height)

Taking 5 and 3 together (which are 2 apart; index 1 and index 3) is the desired result, because it results in the highest area (3 * 2 = 6).

For the second example, some of your other options are:

- 3 and 1: Result is an area of 1 (1 apart * 1 min height)
- 3 and 2: Result is an area of 4 (2 apart * 2 min height)
- 3 and 4: Result is an area of 9 (3 apart * 3 min height)

Etc. The highest result is 3 and 5 (which are 4 apart; index 0 and index 4), which has an area of 12 (3 * 4).

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int maxArea(int[] height) {
    int n = height.length;
    int left = 0;
    int right = n - 1;
    int maxArea = 0;

    while (left < right) {
      
        int area = (right - left) * Math.min(height[left], height[right]);
        maxArea = Math.max(maxArea, area);

        if (height[left] < height[right]) {
            left++;
        }else {
            right--;
        }

    }

    return maxArea;
}
```